# How to give read and write acess to a particular user to acess particular folder in NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, root, ntfs, read-only

I have two users in a system: userA and userB. userA is root user.
I want userB to have read and write access only to a particular folder in an NTFS partition, while the remaining partition will be read-only. Currently both users have read and write access to NTFS partition.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot give user ownership to a folder in an ntfs partition.

Comment: can u explain why not possible? and one more question, can i do the same with ext4 partition. if possible then how?

Answer (score 1):

*NTFS* partitions have a file system designed for Windows. While a Linux file system (for example *ext4*) can store Linux user / group ownership and permission information, an NTFS partition cannot store these. So, in NTFS partitions the "owner" of all the files and folders is the user who mounted the partition. You can see that information for example by doing `ls -al /ntf_partition`.

If this were an *ext4* partition you could have changed the ownership of all the files in the partition (`chown -R root:root /ext4_paritition`) to the *root* user and group (you have called that user *userA* in your case). After that, you could have given the ownership of that specific folder to that specific user (*userB* in your case): `chown -R userB:userB /ext4_paritition/specific_folder`.